# How to make a Scrollable Alert's content in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I try to create a full-screen alert dialog, but I can not scroll inside the content!

How to make a Scrollable Full-screen Alert dialog's content in Jetpack Compose?

```kotlin
package com.compose.example

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.ExperimentalComposeUiApi
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties
import com.compose.example.ui.theme.ComposeExampleTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeExampleTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainContent()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        // * Alert dialog Sample
        Button(
            onClick = {
                openDialog.value=true
            },
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Alert Dialog Sample")
        }
    }

    //Alert Dialog Sample
    if (openDialog.value) {
        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = {
                // Dismiss the dialog when the user clicks outside the dialog or on the back
                // button. If you want to disable that functionality, simply use an empty
                // onDismissRequest.
                openDialog.value = false
            },
            title = {
                Text(text = "Privacy Policy for Compose Example")
            },
            text = {
                Text(text = "At Compose Example, accessible from https://compose-example.blogspot.com/, one of our main priorities is the privacy of our visitors. This Privacy Policy document contains types of information that is collected and recorded by Compose Example and how we use it.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "If you have additional questions or require more information about our Privacy Policy, do not hesitate to contact us.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Log Files\n" +
                        "Compose Example follows a standard procedure of using log files. These files log visitors when they visit websites. All hosting companies do this and a part of hosting services' analytics. The information collected by log files include internet protocol (IP) addresses, browser type, Internet Service Provider (ISP), date and time stamp, referring/exit pages, and possibly the number of clicks. These are not linked to any information that is personally identifiable. The purpose of the information is for analyzing trends, administering the site, tracking users' movement on the website, and gathering demographic information. Our Privacy Policy was created with the help of the Privacy Policy Generator.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Privacy Policies\n" +
                        "You may consult this list to find the Privacy Policy for each of the advertising partners of Compose Example.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Third-party ad servers or ad networks uses technologies like cookies, JavaScript, or Web Beacons that are used in their respective advertisements and links that appear on Compose Example, which are sent directly to users' browser. They automatically receive your IP address when this occurs. These technologies are used to measure the effectiveness of their advertising campaigns and/or to personalize the advertising content that you see on websites that you visit.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Note that Compose Example has no access to or control over these cookies that are used by third-party advertisers.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Third Party Privacy Policies\n" +
                        "Compose Example's Privacy Policy does not apply to other advertisers or websites. Thus, we are advising you to consult the respective Privacy Policies of these third-party ad servers for more detailed information. It may include their practices and instructions about how to opt-out of certain options.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "You can choose to disable cookies through your individual browser options. To know more detailed information about cookie management with specific web browsers, it can be found at the browsers' respective websites.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Children's Information\n" +
                        "Another part of our priority is adding protection for children while using the internet. We encourage parents and guardians to observe, participate in, and/or monitor and guide their online activity.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Compose Example does not knowingly collect any Personal Identifiable Information from children under the age of 13. If you think that your child provided this kind of information on our website, we strongly encourage you to contact us immediately and we will do our best efforts to promptly remove such information from our records.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Online Privacy Policy Only\n" +
                        "This Privacy Policy applies only to our online activities and is valid for visitors to our website with regards to the information that they shared and/or collect in Compose Example. This policy is not applicable to any information collected offline or via channels other than this website.\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "Consent\n" +
                        "By using our website, you hereby consent to our Privacy Policy and agree to its Terms and Conditions.")
            },
            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        openDialog.value = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Accept")
                }
            },
            dismissButton = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        openDialog.value = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Dismiss")
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())` modifier to your content to make it scrollable.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: Is it possible to make the dialog expand in size vertically until it needs to scroll, and then it would scroll? Having trouble figuring this one out.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a supplement to Mr. Adib Faramarzi's answer. How about setting .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) not for AlertDialog but for text(or column)?

Like this

```
AlertDialog(
    text = {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            Text(text = "TITLE", fontSize = 50.sp)
            repeat(30){Text(text = "LONG TEXT")}
            Spacer(modifier.height(5.dp))
        }
    },
    onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
    confirmButton = {
        TextButton(onClick = onDismissRequest) {
            Text(stringResource(id = R.string.close))
        }
    },
)
```